# Why is my code executed in an custom Exception Class when I haven't raised it yet

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, exception

I have 4 files in my project: Tools.py, ProjectGUI.py, ProjectExceptions.py and ProjectMain.py

Most of the utility and code is written in the Tools file, while ProjectMain just calls functions from Tools. I am using a simple GUI with tkinter, written in the ProjectGUI.py file. I have a button asigned to execute the main code from ProjectMain. When I run ProjectMain by itself and I try to raise an exception from ProjectExceptions.py, everything works as expected. However when I try to execute the code using GUI and raise and exception, it doesn't work. The code written inside the Exception class does not execute and my program just freezes.

Here's a sample from the ProjectExceptions.py file:

```
from tkinter.messagebox import showerror


class OffsetNotStable(BaseException):
    def __init__(self):
        showerror(title='Error', message='Not stable')


class VoltageNotWithinTolerance(BaseException):
    def __init__(self):
        showerror(title='Error', message='Voltage not correct')
```

I have the try/except in ProjectMain. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here's a snip of the code from main:

```
class OffsetStableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dwf_ain, tolerance, name, ch, th_q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.ch = ch
        self.dwf_ain = dwf_ain
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.th_q = th_q
        self.exc = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            # print("Starting " + self.name)
            Tools.offset_stable(self.dwf_ain,
                                self.ch,
                                tolerance=self.tolerance,
                                debug_mode=False,
                                th_q=self.th_q)
            # print("Exiting " + self.name)
        except BaseException as e:
            self.exc = e

    def my_join(self):
        threading.Thread.join(self)
        if self.exc:
            raise self.exc


def main():
    thread_to_exit = Queue()
    thread_to_exit.put(False)
    wd_const = DeviceData.Tolerances()
    hdwf = dwf.Dwf(idxCfg=1)
    dwf_ain = dwf.DwfAnalogIn(hdwf)
    try:
        offset_stable_thread_ch1 = OffsetStableThread(dwf_ain,
                                                      wd_const.offset_stable,
                                                      name='Offset stable channel 1',
                                                      ch=0,
                                                      th_q=thread_to_exit)
        offset_stable_thread_ch2 = OffsetStableThread(dwf_ain,
                                                      wd_const.offset_stable,
                                                      name='Offset stable channel 2',
                                                      ch=1,
                                                      th_q=thread_to_exit)
        offset_stable_thread_ch1.setDaemon(True)
        offset_stable_thread_ch2.setDaemon(True)
        offset_stable_thread_ch1.start()
        offset_stable_thread_ch2.start()
        offset_stable_thread_ch1.my_join()
        offset_stable_thread_ch2.my_join()

    except ProjectExceptions.OffsetNotStable:
        hdwf.close()
        return
    except ProjectExceptions.VoltageNotWithinTolerance:
        hdwf.close()
        return
```

Here's the function called from Tools:

```
def offset_stable(dwf_ain, channel, tolerance, debug_mode=False, th_q=None):
    dwf_ain.frequencySet(20e6)
    dwf_ain.bufferSizeSet(4000)
    dwf_ain.channelEnableSet(channel, True)
    dwf_ain.channelRangeSet(channel, 50)

    dc_old = 0
    count = -1
    for tries in range(tolerance['Max tries quota']):

        if th_q:
            if th_q.get():
                return
            else:
                th_q.put(False)

        count += 1
        dwf_ain.configure(False, True)
        while True:
            if dwf_ain.status(True) == dwf_ain.STATE.DONE:
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)

        rgdSamples = dwf_ain.statusData(channel, 4000)
        dc = sum(rgdSamples) / len(rgdSamples)
        if debug_mode:
            print(str(tries) + f"Channel {channel}: DC: " + str(dc) + "V")

        if count < tolerance['Skip entries']:
            continue
        count = 0
        slope = dc - dc_old
        # if debug_mode:
        #     print(f'slope = {slope}\n')
        dc_old = dc
        if slope > tolerance['Slope tolerance']:
            continue
        if debug_mode:
            print('\n', tries)
        return dwf_ain
    th_q.put(True)
    raise ProjectExceptions.OffsetNotStable
```

I am using Queue with th_q variable passed in order to exit from the thread, when an exception is raised from a different thread.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't execute? Or is it possible that it's e.g. showing the message somewhere behind other windows? Or is it being fired from another thread (which is a no-no in Tk land)?

Comment: @AKX I am certain, as I ran a print statement after showerror() and it did not print anything. And the program froze after the raise statement. I am using threading in ProjectMain, getting two threads that run in parralel. When running ProjectMain without GUI, it prints and does not freeze.

Comment: can You show how You put it in the except statement? also I have heard using threading in tkinter can possibly crash it without giving error messages

Comment: You will need to be very careful when using threading with Tkinter (as I alluded to earlier). We'll need more context and code to help.

Comment: I edited to include more code.

Comment: Basically, the exception is raised inside of a thread. Inside of the thread class, I catch the exception and rethrow it to the main thread so the try/except can catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of raising the Exception in the function I returned a string with the Exception name and raised the Exceptions in my_join method in the threading class.

```
def offset_stable(dwf_ain, channel, tolerance, debug_mode=False, th_q=None):
    dwf_ain.frequencySet(20e6)
    dwf_ain.bufferSizeSet(4000)
    dwf_ain.channelEnableSet(channel, True)
    dwf_ain.channelRangeSet(channel, 50)

    dc_old = 0
    count = -1
    for tries in range(tolerance['Max tries quota']):

        if th_q:
            if th_q.get():
                return
            else:
                th_q.put(False)

        count += 1
        dwf_ain.configure(False, True)
        while True:
            if dwf_ain.status(True) == dwf_ain.STATE.DONE:
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)

        rgdSamples = dwf_ain.statusData(channel, 4000)
        dc = sum(rgdSamples) / len(rgdSamples)
        if debug_mode:
            print(str(tries) + f"Channel {channel}: DC: " + str(dc) + "V")

        if count < tolerance['Skip entries']:
            continue
        count = 0
        slope = dc - dc_old
        # if debug_mode:
        #     print(f'slope = {slope}\n')
        dc_old = dc
        if slope > tolerance['Slope tolerance']:
            continue
        if debug_mode:
            print('\n', tries)
        return dwf_ain
    th_q.put(True)
    return 'OffsetNotStable'
```

```
class OffsetStableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, dwf_ain, tolerance, name, ch, th_q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.ch = ch
        self.dwf_ain = dwf_ain
        self.tolerance = tolerance
        self.th_q = th_q
        self.offset = None

    def run(self):
        # print("Starting " + self.name)
        self.offset = Tools.offset_stable(self.dwf_ain,
                                          self.ch,
                                          tolerance=self.tolerance,
                                          debug_mode=False,
                                          th_q=self.th_q)
        # print("Exiting " + self.name)

    def my_join(self):
        threading.Thread.join(self)
        if self.offset == 'OffsetNotStable':
            raise TesterExceptions.OffsetNotStable
```